# Deleting mysql table entry with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-delete

Basically, what I want to delete an entry form a dataviewtable which pulls data through from MySql. I thought this would be done fairly by effectively copying the modify code and substituting it for 'DELETE'. However, from the code below, you can clearly see that hasn't worked. I will copy most of my code for you:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-HNR3NJB\\mysql;Initial Catalog=stock;Integrated Security=True");
    var sqlQuery = "";
    if (IfProductsExists(con, textboxProductID.Text))
    {
        con.Open();
        sqlQuery = @"DELETE FROM [Products] WHERE [ProductID] = '" + textboxProductID.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Record doesn't exist!", "ERROR:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    //Reading Data
    LoadData();
}
```

So that's the delete button's code now for the add button and load data function

Add button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-HNR3NJB\mysql;Initial Catalog=stock;Integrated Security=True");
    //insert logic
    con.Open();
    if(textboxProductID.Text == "" || textboxProductName.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have to enter either a product ID or product name", "Error:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        bool status = false;
        if (comboboxStatus.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            status = true;
        }
        else
        {
            status = false;
        }

        var sqlQuery = "";

        if (IfProductsExists(con, textboxProductID.Text))
        {
            sqlQuery = @"UPDATE [Products] SET [ProductName] = '" + textboxProductName.Text + "' ,[ProductStatus] = '" + status + "' WHERE [ProductID] = '" + textboxProductID.Text + "'";
        }
        else
        {
            sqlQuery = @"INSERT INTO [Stock].[dbo].[Products] ([ProductID],[ProductName],[ProductStatus]) VALUES
                    ('" + textboxProductID.Text + "','" + textboxProductName.Text + "','" + status + "')";
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();


        textboxProductID.Clear();
        textboxProductName.Clear();

        LoadData();
    }

}
```

`LoadData` function:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-HNR3NJB\mysql;Initial Catalog=stock;Integrated Security=True");

    //reading data from sql
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From [stock].[dbo].[Products]", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["ProductID"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["ProductName"].ToString();
        if ((bool)item["ProductStatus"])
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = "Active";
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = "Deactive";
        }
    }
}
```

You're going to need the `IfProductsExists` method too:

```
private bool IfProductsExists(SqlConnection con, string productCode)
{
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select 1 From [Products] WHERE [ProductID]='" + productCode + "'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

It's going to be an inventory system that's going to be used at work for the sale and inventory management of IT equipment.

Comment: "you can clearly see that hasn't worked" - how come we can clearly see it hasn't worked ?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question but please use parameters - your current code is vulnerable to sql injection. Someone can potentially drop your database entering proper SQL script into your textbox. Please find [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) article

Comment: Okay I apologize for my wording, you can't clearly see that it doesn't work, but it doesn't.

Thank you so much for the link to that article and I will definitely look in to it for further applications, however I believe I should be okay with this application as it's only being used by me and my boss at work for the time being. Of course if i was to ever release the application, I would look in to that.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working ? Which part of your code ? Is it failing to delete record from the database, or maybe it's just display issue ? Please provide more details of an issue so we can help you.

Comment: If it's just the issue that DataGrid is not updating - you need to update it explicitly by executing following: dataGridView1.Update();